# Extracting Uneven Data From Text File

Tags: c++, string, file

I have a data file which contains values for nine different variables on each line: `x`, `y`, `z`, `v_x`, `v_y`, `v_z`, `m`, `ID`, `V`. I am writing a program to extract just the `x`, `y`, and `z` values from the data file. I am relatively new to this type of procedure, and I am running into problems doing this because the values are not always of the same length. An example of a portion of the data file is here (only the `x`, `y`, `z` columns):

```
2501.773926 1701.783081 211.1383057

1140.961426 4583.300781 322.4959412 

1194.471313 5605.764648 1377.315552 

506.1424866 6037.965332 1119.67041  

213.5106354 5788.785156 2340.610352 

59.43727493 5914.666016 2357.921143 

1223.028564 4292.818848 3007.292725 

4445.61377  3684.48999  2903.169189 

5649.732422 4596.819824 2661.301025 

5741.396973 5503.06543  2412.082031 

4806.246094 5587.194336 2676.126465 

4855.521973 5482.893066 2743.014648 

5190.890625 5399.349121 1549.1698
```

Note how in most instances the length of each number is eleven spaces, but this is not always the case. The code that I have written is here:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// data created by Gadget2
const string gadget_data("particles_64cubed.txt");

int main()
{

cout << "GADGET2: Extracting Desired Data From ASCII File." << endl;

// declaring vectors to store the data
int bins = 135000000; // 512^3 particles = 134,217,728 particles
vector<double> x(bins), y(bins), z(bins);


// read the data file
ifstream data_file(gadget_data.c_str());
if (data_file.fail()) 
{
    cerr << "Cannot open " << gadget_data << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} 
else
    cout << "Reading data file: " << gadget_data << endl;
string line;
int particles = 0;
while (getline(data_file, line)) 
{
    string x_pos = line.substr(0, 11);
    double x_val = atof(x_pos.c_str());    // atof converts string to double
    string y_pos = line.substr(12, 11);
    double y_val = atof(y_pos.c_str());
    string z_pos = line.substr(24, 11);
    double z_val = atof(z_pos.c_str());

    if (particles < bins) 
    {
        x[particles] = x_val;
        y[particles] = y_val;
        z[particles] = z_val;
        ++particles;
    }
}
data_file.close();
cout << "Stored " << particles << " particles in positions_64.dat" << endl;

vector<double> x_values, y_values, z_values;
for (int i = 0; i < particles; i++) 
{
    x_values.push_back(x[i]);
    y_values.push_back(y[i]);
    z_values.push_back(z[i]);
}

// write desired data to file
ofstream new_file("positions_64.dat");
for (int i = 0; i < x_values.size(); i++)
    new_file << x_values[i] << '\t' << y_values[i] << '\t' << z_values[i] << endl;
new_file.close();
cout << "Wrote desired data to file: " << "positions_64.dat" << endl;

}
```

The code obviously fails because of the non-constant lengths for each value. Does anyone know of another method to achieve this? Perhaps something other than substring and spanning a specific length of characters, but something that grabs the values up to a white space? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You find the delimiters and then substring it based on that rather than a fixed number.

Comment: check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/5447209) that provides a function for splitting a string based on a user supplied delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are already reading the file using `ifstream` and `getline`. Why did you fall back to cutting the line into chunks of N characters and `atof`'ing them? I mean, iostreams can read and write into integers, doubles, etc, best seen on the example of `cin` and `cout`.

There's a `istringstream` class which would easily help you:

```
std::istringstream input(line); // line is std::string from getline()
double x,y,z;
if(input >> x >> y >> z) // just this! and it's already a simple error check
    ; // do something with x,y,z
else
    ; // handle the error
```

It should just work, because you already have line-by-line reading, and because the data is separated by whitespaces, which are by default ignored by `>>` operator.

FYI: [istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/istringstream/)

Comment: This did the job, many thanks! The only issue is that I am losing some of the significant figures from the original data. The data file produced has two decimal places at best, rather than up to seven. Any ideas?

Comment: @LeighK: I don't recall any issues with operator `>>`. It should read every digit in sequence and try to fit it into the double, so you should observe precision losses only caused by the double itself. I think that may be because of some default precision setting for operator `<<`, so at the moment when you are writing to file. Please try `new_file << setprecision(16) << x_values[i]` or something similar. Please see i.e. [this example I just did](https://ideone.com/nD0Ph9) and see how unconfigured `cout` trims doubles to 6 digits. I suppose it's the same case for your `ofstream new_file`.